# How can I display the default enum value in ItemDisplayBinding in the Picker of Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

View:

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding ECCLevels}" 
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel}"
        HeightRequest="44"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel> ECCLevels { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel>();

ECCLevels = new ObservableCollection<QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel)).OfType<QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel>().ToList());
```

I simplified the code above. The ObservableCollection gets filled with data after the second line of code. But the problem is I don't know what to put in the ItemDisplayBinding property of the picker since there the Enum gets converted into a list directly without going through a model.

Comment: Probably simply: `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding .}"`?

Comment: Thank you @GeraldVersluis. It works. How'd you know though? I can't find any documentation mentioning this.

Comment: Created an answer out of it, glad to be of service!

Comment: {Binding .} is just shorthand for binding directly to the bindingcontext object with no path, you might also be able to just use {Binding}

Comment: Yes @BenReierson, it works as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding .}"`, the dot notation means that you refer to `this` basically. So, this way you simply reference the object itself and not any other property.

In the comments you asked me how I know, that is actually I great question. I think I picked it up as early as WPF. But it's hard to dig up from the documentation, I found a small notice of it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.path?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Data_Binding_Path

> Optionally, a period (.) path can be used to bind to the current source. For example, `Text="{Binding}"` is equivalent to `Text="{Binding Path=.}"`.

Comment: I need to RaisePropertyChange for the ObservableCollection... Is it normal behavior doing it?